# loop for end before it should

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a function when paired with a gui which is composed of two listboxes. The function detect all the item selected in both listboxes and export for each items data in two different excel sheets. Once all the data have been exported i want the function to rename all the sheets here is how it should work if there is 7 selection in the first listbox and 5 in the second listbox

In the excel file the 7 selection of nb (first listbox) will be on the 14 first sheets and the 5 selection of ne (second listbox) will take the sheets 15 to 24. (each item selected takes two sheet)

the code will proceed like this ;

```
for i = 1:(length(nb))
rename sheet 1 f=1
rename sheet 2 g=2 
f = 3, g=4 
rename sheet 3 f=3
rename sheet 4 f=4
f=5, g=6
...
at the end of the for f = 15 and g =16
end 
then come the second loop for 
for i = 1:(length(ne))
rename sheet 15 f=15
rename sheet 16 g=16
f=17, g=18
rename sheet 17 f=17
rename sheet 18 f=18
f=19, g=20
...
at the end of the second loop f=25 and g=26
```

and here the problem that can be seen f and g never gets to the number they should they would always end before.

here is the part of my code that do this :

```
f = 1
g = 2
for i = 1:(length(nb)) %length(nb) represent the number of items selected in the first listbox
myExcel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
excelWorkBook = myExcel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\223080038\Desktop\data.xlsx',0,false);
excelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(f).Name = [Varlist1{1,nb(1,i)} ' Spectre tension']; 
excelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(g).Name = [Varlist1{1,nb(1,i)} ' Impédence']; 
excelWorkBook.Save;
excelWorkBook.Close;
f =f+2
g=g+2
end
f = 1 
g = 2
for e = 1:(length(ne)) %length(nE) represent the number of items selected in the first listbox
myExcel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
excelWorkBook = myExcel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\223080038\Desktop\data.xlsx',0,false);
excelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(f).Name = [Varlist2{1,ne(1,e)} ' Spectre Courant']; 
excelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(g).Name = [Varlist2{1,ne(1,e)} ' Spectre tension']; 
excelWorkBook.Save;
excelWorkBook.Close;
myExcel.Quit;
f=f+2
g=g+2
end
```

Comment: Before the second loop you reset `f` to 1 and `g` to 2, and then you wonder why they have those values at the start of the second loop?

Comment: Well that was an easy fix. I didn't see that i thought it would be more complicated thx for the help